# How to maintain dropdown option value even after switching between components in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

So basically i have two tab view or 2 tabs. The first tab has multiple dropdowns and the second dropdown have nothing .So if i select values from the tab which has dropdowns and switch to the second tab the values which i have selected is gone .
Basically the state is not being maintained .

My issue is how to maintain the state or the values of the selected dropdowns even if i switch between tabs

With basic reactjs solution no redux or hooks.

Comment: You might take a look into the state management using HOC: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a problem global state solutions such as redux solve.  Since you'd like to use a vanilla react solution I'd suggest either lifting the state to the parent of both components or using Context API - you can read about Context here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Lifting state up basically means moving the place you declare state and the function that changes state up to the parent of *both* components.  Then you can pass down the state *and* the function that changes state as props allowing both components to share that state as well as have the ability to change state.

If this is just a small amount of data or something simple I'd go with lifting state up.  If it's going to grow over time I'd use Context.

Good luck!